# Oracle DELETE sql with JOIN doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

My delete statement returns a 933 error in Oracle, I'm not sure what is wrong-

```
DELETE b
from temp a
JOIN
  fact_tab b
on a.col1 = b.col1
and a.col2 = b.col2
and a.col3 = b.col3;
```

Both tables dont have a primary key. select statement on the same thing works-

```
select * 
from temp a
JOIN
  fact_tab b
on a.col1 = b.col1
and a.col2 = b.col2
and a.col3 = b.col3;
```

Comment: Where in the manual did you find the syntax to use a `JOIN` for a `DELETE` statement? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505

Comment: My mistake, I am not deeply familiar with Oracle. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+delete+join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow JOIN in a DELETE statement directly like that.

You could do the delete in the following way:

```
DELETE
FROM fact_tab
WHERE ROWID IN
  (SELECT b.rowid
  FROM temp a
  JOIN fact_tab b
  ON a.col1  = b.col1
  AND A.col2 = b.col2
  AND A.col3 = b.col3
  );
```

You could also use `WHERE EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
DELETE FROM
  fact_tab
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      temp
    WHERE
      temp.col1 = fact_tab.col1 AND
      temp.col2 = fact_tab.col2 AND
      temp.col2 = fact_tab.col2
  )
```